# How do I get the gradient expression when implementing a specific neural network?

Tags: c++, math, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I mean if I want to implement a normal neural network, it's easy to find the gradient or derivative expression anywhere, but when I implement a specific neural network, its's not that easy. So, normally, when you do that you get gradient expression by hand or you use some tool? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you trying to implement this in a specific programming language?  Can you post some code?  As your question stands, it's more of a mathematics question and belongs in a different forum.

Comment: I used to implement neural neworks with theano. With that, you know, I don't have to compute gradient myself. But I'll use c++ to implement neural networks so I have to compute the gradient myself. So now I consider this kind of problem before I meet it in future.

Comment: This is more likely a statistics question because it requires understanding of the gradient decent algorithm.

Comment: By the way, the specific algorithms are usually read from a research paper. There is no such thing like a table of formulas that you can just copy and paste.

Comment: I mean maybe I can use a tool when I give it the feed forward function, it can compute the gradient backward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theano can tell you the symbolic expression for the gradient. The only problem is that it can take a little effort to interpret the output.

For example, let `x`, `w`, and `b` be a scalars, and

```
y = x * w + b
```

In Theano this can be implemented as

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

x = tt.scalar('x')
w = tt.scalar('w')
b = tt.scalar('b')
y = x * w + b
g = tt.grad(y, w)
theano.printing.debugprint(g)
f = theano.function([x, w, b], outputs=g)
theano.printing.debugprint(f)
```

When executed (using the current bleeding edge version of Theano) this script will print

```
Elemwise{mul} [id A] ''   
 |Elemwise{second,no_inplace} [id B] ''   
 | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [id C] ''   
 | | |Elemwise{mul,no_inplace} [id D] ''   
 | | | |x [id E]
 | | | |w [id F]
 | | |b [id G]
 | |TensorConstant{1.0} [id H]
 |x [id E]

DeepCopyOp [id A] 'x'   0
 |x [id B]
```

The first output is the unoptimized gradient expression. The second is the optimized gradient expression.

As we know from our differential calculus class, for the given expression of `y`,

```
dy/dw = x
```

And this is exactly what we see from Theano.

So you can build your neural network in Theano and then print the automatically derived symbolic gradient to see what it should be, then implement that expression in your alternate implementation.

For more complex networks interpreting the symbolic gradient from Theano can be very tedious and it's probably easier to learn the necessary maths to derive the gradients yourself, especially if using reasonably standard neural network constructs. The Theano automatic differentiation could then be used to verify your manual derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Using and neural network architecture, the formulas for the gradient decent learning should be computed. If you're using a neural network package like caffe or torch, you'll just have to specify if you'll be working on the negative log likelihood or the mean square error or what (this is what changes the learning rule). The formulas would be done automatically. However, if you're writing your own neural network platform, you'll need to do some math or just get the formulas from a paper or something. There is no tool that works as a formula finder for the neural networks learning.

Comment: Actually there are kinda are. You can use symbolic differentiators (sympy), you can use automatic differentation (autograd)

Comment: And Theano is a symbolic differentiator the OP is apparently familiar with.